# Saving data using AJAX in rails with hidden input, the data is saved, but hidden field always saving zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am a newbie in ruby on rails it's also my first ruby application. I am trying to save data using ajax with hidden input field the data is saving, but hidden field saving zero in each click.

The below is my source codes

**View file: resumes.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for :saved_resume, url: resumes_path(@saved_resume), remote: true, html: { id: 'resums' }  do |f| %>
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
     <li>
       <%= f.hidden_field :jobseeker_id, :value => params[:jobseeker_id] %>
     </li>
     <li>
       <input id="resume" type="submit" value="Save resume" />
     </li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

**JS code**

```
$("input").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:    "/resumes",
    data: {saved_resume: { jobseeker_id: "jobseeker_id", recruiter_id: "recruiter_id"}},
    datatype:"html",
    async: false
  });
});
```

**Controller Code:**

```
 def create

    params.permit!
    @saved_resume = @recruiter.saved_resumes.create(saved_resume_params)
    if @saved_resume.save
     redirect_to resumes_path, notice: "Save process completed!"
     else
      render :resumes
     end
    end
   private
   def saved_resume_params
      params.require(:saved_resume).permit(:jobseeker_id)
   end
```

My table name is `saved_resumes` here, and `jobseeker_id` & `recruiter_id` are the foreign keys.

Comment: Write `return render json: params` in the beginning of the method `create`, and copy-paste that response in your question.

Comment: `return render json: params` will just print your `params` hash in your browser. Alternatively, you can copy the `params` hash from your development logs as well. You can see your development logs in the terminal where you have run `rails s`.

Comment: Thanks :) you can add this in the desired place by editing the question, please.  @Bilal

Comment: You need to add this to your code on your local, re-fill the form, and press the submit button. Then you are gonna see the `params` hash in your browser. Does it make sense?

Comment: I added the code before def create it's showing the below error  "undefined local variable or method `params' for ResumesController:Class"